# Perguntas fora do âmbito técnico-prático

Tags: debate

Peço desculpas pelo título, mas a princípio não achei nada  melhor.

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15157/licenca-do-dreamspark-posso-usar-em-mais-de-uma-maquina) me fez pensar. O autor diz o seguinte:

> Não li os termos de uso na hora de fazer o download, e agora gostaria de saber se posso usar as mesmas licenças tanto em meu notebook como no meu Desktop sem infringir o EULA.

Em outras palavras, o que ele *realmente* quer é: "*alguém sem preguiça pode ler o EULA pra mim e dizer se posso fazer isso?*"

Portanto, pergunto: seria essa uma pergunta válida? Eu iria sugerir para fechar, mas não encontrei nenhuma infração que ela se encaixasse. Tem contexto, é específica (*não-ampla*) e as respostas não são baseadas em opiniões.

Comment: De acordo com [esse item](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/792/215) na lista (votação, pesquisa de opinião) de assuntos on e off topic, esse tipo de pergunta seria aceita sim. Não há consenso entretanto - o item está com +9/-5. Talvez seja uma boa ideia aprofundar a discussão aqui.

Comment: A opção correta para perguntas off-topic é sinalizá-las como "descontextualizadas", dentro de "ela deve ser encerrada por outro motivo...". Não estou dizendo que é o caso agora.

Comment: Obrigado Math e mgibsonbr pelos pareceres, entretanto, puxem uma cadeira e vamos conversar! A princípio, eu acho essa pergunta *fora de escopo* porque entra justamente naquele conceito de redundância. Nós não devemos falar em nome das empresas ou de termos de uso - é de responsabilidade de cada usuário ter conhecimento sobre o produto proprietário que estiver usando. Ainda mais nesse caso em específico, é aparente a preguiça do OP de dar uma lida no EULA. Achei desnecessário. Além disso, pode ocorrer do EULA mudar no futuro e a resposta virar desinformação, por mais que esteja datada.

Comment: Eu fui um dos que votou negativamente neste tópico porque pela minha experiência esse tipo de pergunta não produz resultados positivos. Além disso, se não for preguiça, só um advogado especializado pode ajudar.

Comment: @bigown Realmente, eu também penso que não produz bons resultados. Eu acredito, talvez, que nem seja às vezes nem seja a questão de um advogado. A princípio, se uma boa leitura e interpretação não for suficiente, o usuário que entre em contato com a Microsoft.

Comment: @bigown não tem nenhum voto negativo aqui

Comment: @Math Eu também pensei que seria para este meu tópico em que estamos à comentar, mas na verdade ele se refere ao tópico vinculado, hehe.

Comment: @Math :) No tópico neste link http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/792/215

Comment: @bigown obrigado pelo esclarecimento, meu próximo comentário ia ser: _"na pergunta linkada pelo autor só tem um voto negativo, entretanto duas pessoas afirmam ter votado negativamente nele"_, rs

Comment: @Math e não é para negativar mesmo, eu fecharia. Só não votei porque vou aguardar o debate aqui. Embora eu muitas vezes vote negativamente em perguntas fechadas também. Odeio ver perguntas fechadas com votos positivos :) Por outro lado tem algumas perguntas fechadas indevidamente que está difícil reabrir :) Mas o que me entristece é uma resposta lá na pergunta baseada totalmente em opinião receber 4 votos até agora.

Comment: Será que o título mais adequado não seria "Perguntas de âmbito jurídico/legal" ?

Comment: Eu não usei a definição "jurídico/legal" porque o contexto não é só esse. Já vi perguntas, por exemplo, sobre tecnologias específicas que também não cabiam aqui. Se/quando eu ver um tópico nessa temática, volto para atualizar.

Answer (score 6):

O que observo na rede Stack Exchange em geral é que são rejeitadas perguntas que exijam uma *expertise* bastante específica (ex.: Direito) e cujos métodos atuais não sejam adequados para avaliar se tal usuário possui ou não essa expertise. *Me parece* que o Area 51 [está sendo reformulado](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8922/54808) de modo a - entre outras coisas - viabilizar esse tipo de site, não tenho certeza...

Mas no momento, se uma pergunta tal como a linkada fosse feita em qualquer outro site da rede, a resposta correta seria "consulte um advogado". Pessoalmente, não sou tão radical (creio que certas noções, principalmente envolvendo software livre, podem sim ser transmitidas por leigos), mas de um modo geral sou da mesma opinião. Nesse caso por exemplo, não só há o problema da temporalidade (como já citado) mas também a impossibilidade de se avaliar uma resposta como correta ou não sem que se tenha *exatamente* o mesmo trabalho de quem respondeu - ler ambos os EULAs inteiros e interpretá-los conforme seu conhecimento.

Quanto a "ter preguiça de ler o EULA", isso todos temos, e seria ótimo passar essa tarefa pra outra pessoa - desde que tívessemos meios de **confiar** no relato dessa pessoa. Se esse site estivesse cheio de advogados, por exemplo... Mas também se alguém **já usou** ambos os produtos na sua empresa e essa questão já tenha sido levantada no seu departamento jurídico (i.e. a pessoa tem experiência prévia, e bons motivos para acreditar que é ou não possível conciliar ambos os EULAs).

Em outras palavras, é possível a princípio responder a essa pergunta **sem ter de [re]ler o EULA**.

É nesse sentido que eu penso que *talvez* esse tipo de pergunta possa encontrar espaço aqui. Se uma ferramenta é bastante popular entre desenvolvedores, já tendo sida provavelmente usada em muitos projetos reais, há sempre a chance de se encontrar alguém cuja experiência pessoal lhe permita dar *insights* valiosos ou chamar a atenção para detalhes que já lhe causaram dor-de-cabeça.

Por isso creio que os dois lados têm de ser pesados: se a pergunta está de tal forma que nenhuma resposta - por mais correta que pareça ou mais completa que seja - possa ser **aceita como certa**, então com certeza ela não é adequada ao formato do site. Caso contrário, não vejo mal algum em dar uma chance a ela...

Comment: Uma questão bem colocada é o fato de esse tipo de pergunta dar vão ao compartilhamento de uma situação que algum indivíduo ou empresa já passara, encurtando o caminho do OP de (re)ler o EULA. Sim, de fato que todos nós temos preguiça de ler EULAs, mas é uma responsabilidade nossa. Eu acho diferente perguntar "*o que a licença MIT diz respeito?*" a "*posso distribuir esse software?*", uma vez tendo explícita a licença por ele utilizada.

Comment: Além disso, eu acho que responder algo desse gênero exige muita responsabilidade e confiabilidade. Imaginemos que uma resposta errada - com ou sem malícia - pode acabar por comprometer o OP, e todos sabemos que nós, usuários de boa índole, não queremos isso. Portanto, eu sou da opinião de que esse tipo de informação deveria ficar imparcialmente por cargo de quem precisa. Penso que o máximo que deveríamos contribuir seja com algo como "*você pode encontrar a sua resposta neste link [link aqui]...*".

Comment: Sobre preguiça - se ao invés de uma EULA fosse alguma documentação técnica, você ainda teria a mesma opinião? i.e.: `não li a documentação do método replace da classe string, alguém poderia me dizer se o enésimo parâmetro pode ser uma expressão regular(...)`

Comment: @Renan Documentação não são termos legais. Além disso, você generalizou com sensacionalismo. A maioria das perguntas do SO são por falta de leitura - isso não é novidade pra ninguém. Só que isso a gente não pode penalizar - tem vezes que não sabemos onde encontrar a solução; outrora, o OP pode não saber que a solução está na documentação: e isso é muito contrário ao caso do nosso amigo Arthur.

Comment: [Tipo **esta aqui**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15216/quais-procedimentos-legais-e-recomendados-para-lancamento-de-uma-aplicacao-web) que acabou de pipocar. Me parece on-topic já que pergunta por um checklist *do que* perguntar ao advogado.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimamente está complicado postar no SOPT. Daqui a alguns tempos imagino que para cada post no SOPT existirá um respectivo post no Meta discutindo a sua validade. Guilherme Oderdenge, com todo respeito, é uma irresponsabilidade da sua parte negativar uma pergunta que de acordo com você mesmo "***[...] não encontrei nenhuma infração que ela se encaixasse. Tem contexto, é específica (não-ampla) e as respostas não são baseadas em opiniões.***"

A alguns dias eu coloquei um pouco de contexto em uma pergunta, explicando a situação, e o bigown editou a pergunta falando que que "***Ninguém está interessado na estória da sua vida***". Agora nesse post tentei ser o mais sucinto possível e sou tachado categoricamente de "***preguiçoso***" (o que eu acredito que seja uma declaração de baixo nível).

O que eu não coloquei na pergunta é que eu já havia procurado em vários lugares a resposta para esta pergunta. Já havia perguntado em forúns e grupos, e sempre me respondiam com "eu acho", resolvi então colocar aqui, já que as perguntas tem a proposta de serem livres de opinião e factuais.

Procurei nos lugares errados? Talvez sim, mas não foi "**preguiça**", pois vasculhei dentro do DreamSpark por bastante tempo antes de considerar fazer esta pergunta. E fiz a pergunta no SOPT porquê tenho muito apreço pelo fato de ter um site da rede em nosso idioma, mas como não temos um site como o SuperUser (onde vi vários perguntas neste escopo. Ex: https://superuser.com/q/53400, https://superuser.com/q/240599) resolvi perguntar por aqui.

Até mesmo porque depois de acompanhar vários debates no meta, lembro que foi falado que devido ao fato de não termos outros sites da rede em nosso idioma, o SOPT seria mais flexível com perguntas que se feitas no SOEN, deveriam ser transferidas para outros sites da rede.

Acho que o que falta mesmo é consenso, porque se eu soubesse que não poderia ter postado esta questão, acreditem que eu não teria feito. Tenho interesse na melhoria do SOPT e no crescimento da nossa comunidade, mas não tenho alegria em ser repreendido sem bases bem fundamentadas.

Comment: Sempre especifique na sua pergunta quais abordagens e pesquisas fez antes de postar isso ajuda quem vai responder eliminando algumas hipóteses além de demonstra que vc teve iniciativa de entender melhor o problema e não quer apenas código pronto ou que alguém faça o seu trabalho.

Comment: Vou ter isso em mende em minhas próximas perguntas @perdeu. É que existe uma febre tão grande de cobrança para que o usuário seja sucinto, que fiquei com receio de causar problema nessa outra ponta. Mas vou tentar equilibrar os dois aspectos.

Comment: Eu vi aquele resumo de edição falando da "estória da sua vida"... Me parece ofensivo também e dei um upvote no seu comentário lá. . . . Neste caso, acho que concordo, você diz que não leu e está pedindo pra alguém ler pra você. Mas, *por favor*, note que são duas coisas diferentes: "**atitude** preguiçosa" e "**pessoa** preguiçosa". . . . O problema aqui (e que faz esse tópico ser off em vários sites) é basicamente "você vai confiar num estranho na Internet pra te dar consultoria jurídica?"

Comment: Entendo @brasofilo. Resolvi perguntar aqui porque as perguntas no SO são conhecidas por serem factuais e baseadas em fontes sólidas. Nesta pergunta por exemplo, a resposta possui um link oficial (Que na realidade era o que eu queria, não uma interpretação, posso ter me expressado errado), dentro do próprio DreamSpark, o que imagino que muitos estejam pensando é "A resposta estava lá no site, porque esse cara não leu?" Mas infelizmente não consegui encontrá-la. Mas entendo seu ponto de vista e agradeço pela última dica.

Comment: Pegando o início e o final do que você disse: tem muita coisa mesmo na zona cinzenta ainda, e por isso os casos *precisam* ser discutidos no meta. É para isso mesmo que serve a fase beta do site. Mais alguns pontos: (1) a pergunta não se encaixar em nenhuma razão de fechamento não significa que não possa receber downvotes, são coisas diferentes; em última instância, cada um pode votar contra o que bem quiser (mesmo existindo diretrizes quanto ao uso desses votos). (2) Mostrar esforço de pesquisa não significa dizer "já procurei no google e em fóruns" [continua...]

Comment: ... Significa sim dizer até onde sua pesquisa já te levou, no sentido de deixar sua dúvida mais específica. No caso da pergunta em questão, por exemplo, valeria a pena citar alguns dos pontos que achou na pesquisa, mesmo não confiando muito naquelas opiniões.

Comment: Terei isto em mente nas próximas perguntas @bfavaretto. Não encarem por favor minha resposta como tentativa de afronta a comunidade, gosto muito da maneira como o site funciona, e estou disposto a sempre que necessário mudar meu comportamento a fim de ajudar no melhor funcionamento do mesmo. Espero que no futuro minhas questões não voltem a constar no Meta. :)

Comment: Tranquilo Arthur, não vejo como afronta não. Nem vejo as discussões do meta como agressão a nenhuma pergunta, resposta ou usuário em particular. Na maioria dos casos, o que se quer aqui é debater o que é melhor para o site. Se no futuro um post seu virar assunto no meta de novo, não leve para o lado pessoal. O que está em debate é o conteúdo e o formato da pergunta.

Comment: A sua pergunta tem vários defeitos no *meu* ponto de vista. Um deles é o fato de ser uma pergunta específica que você sabe sim onde encontrar a resposta; outra, não encontrou a resposta no EULA que a Microsoft disponibilizou? Você é membro do DreamSpark - entre em contato com eles e faça a pergunta, oras! Eu tenho BizSpark e quando eventualmente me surge um problema específico como esse, solicito que me liguem ou abro um ticket e em questão de no máximo uns dois dias eu tenho a resposta de volta.

Comment: Eu achei muito sensacionalista a forma como você se pronunciou aqui. Eu não quis ser agressivo e tampouco íntimo: não me importo com quem você é, eu só quero consistência comunitária e tento colaborar o máximo para isso; para tanto, achei a sua pergunta inválida e desnecessária pro SOPT, por isso assim eu fiz esse manifesto. E mais, sobre o SuperUser: ué, se lá eles tem condição de resolver o seu problema, por que você não fez a mesma pergunta lá? Por mais flexível que estejamos sendo, nós ainda assim temos um foco.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Os seus primeiros comentários na minha pergunta foram de alto nível, e quando os li, imaginei sim que a minha pergunta poderia ter sido melhor elaborada, ou que não procurei ajuda no melhor local, até aí fiquei até mesmo grato por sua disposição em me dar este conselho. Mas daí quando vi a maneira como você redigiu esta pergunta aqui no Meta, fiquei sim muito desapontado. Olha o que você escreveu: "alguém sem preguiça pode ler o EULA pra mim e dizer se posso fazer isso?" Viramos forum de games? Onde ofensas são trocadas livremente?

Comment: Enfim, não achei errado você ter me orientado sobre a natureza da pergunta, mas sim por você, sem me conhecer, assumir que sou apenas alguém com preguiça de ler documentação, sugando ajuda no SO. Se não a li é porque não a havia encontrado, e novamente, agora reconheço que aqui não foi o melhor lugar para perguntar isso.

Comment: A impressão que você me passou é essa, de verdade. Se tem um lugar onde a resposta definitiva para a sua pergunta pode ser encontrada, é no EULA. O que você estava fazendo, baseado na forma que você redigiu a pergunta e na minha interpretação e ponto de vista, era repassando o trabalho de interpretação. Se não foi isso, você poderia lapidar um pouco mais a sua questão para ampliar o nosso entendimento sobre a situação. Mas lembre-se: não importa o quão polida a pergunta fique, o contexto é o mesmo, que, pra mim, é inválido.

Comment: E pra mim é contraditório você falar que achou os meus primeiros comentários de alto nível. A impressão que essa sua resposta passa é de que o meu manifesto não tem muita vasão. A maneira como você se defendeu, a minha tachação "categória" sobre você *ser* preguiçoso... enfim, tudo isso me leva a crer que você realmente não achou a minha expressão tão elegante. De qualquer forma, o SO não é feito de achismos, portanto, vou me redimir e pedir desculpas se algo saiu do controle - mas eis a minha maneira de enfatizar uma situação, seja ela ruim ou não.

Comment: Tudo bem @GuilhermeOderdenge. Essa conversa já passou do ponto onde poderia ser produtiva. Entendo que você está tentando ajudar a comunidade, eu estou disposto a me adequar ao que a comunidade definir como melhor. Em minhas próximas perguntas evitarei deixar passar essa mesma impressão, e também peço desculpas pelas más impressões que minha resposta lhe passaram. Sinceramente.